# Detect in script whether being run via normal PowerShell window, or Exchange Management Shell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Does anyone know of a way to detect within a PowerShell script if it's being run from within a normal PowerShell window or from the Exchange Management Shell?

Some functionality that works in one doesn't work in the other, or produces different results, so I want to detect which UI the user is using to run the script, and then where appropriate direct them to use the other.

Comment: Take a look at the automatic `$Host` variable

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I can't verify it myself, but doesn't the EMS run in a regular  console window? If so, I'd look for the presence of EMS-specific cmdlets (or modules), with something like `$isEMS = [bool] (Get-Command -ea Ignore Get-ExCommand)`

Comment: @mklement0 Awesome, yes that does the trick, thanks. Also checked $host, but the way the EMS works the $host output is identical whether you're in EMS or not.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mklement0 for the suggestion

Confirmed his solution works, eg :

```
$isEMS = [bool] (Get-Command –eq Ignore Get-ExCommand)
if ($isEMS)
{ Write-Host “Using EMS” }
Else
{ Write-Host “Using normal PS }
```

Also checked and confirmed this works even if you’re using the Exchange snapin (eg Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Snapin) in your script in the normal PS window, so the query only seems to pick up if you’re using the EMS specifically, not that you’re working with Exchange in general which is what I was after.